# Python 3, difference between print("x:\n{}".format(x)) and print("x:\n",x)?

Tags: python-3.x, printing

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
print("x:\n{}".format(x))
print("x:\n",x)
```

what is the difference between `print("x:\n{}".format(x))` and `print("x:\n",x)` ?

I do not understand the concept of `print("x:\n{}".format(x))` and how it works!
when you say .format  what is the dot referring to? to what ever is inside ""?
why we need {}?

Thanks

Comment: `"x:\n{}".format(x)` returns a string which is then printed, while the second example passes 2 arguments to the `print function`, one which is a string, and one which is a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The curly braces are to *contain* **"replacement"** fields [that describe to the format engine what should be placed in the output](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/#id17). That is, they are *special characters* the parser uses to determine how to format a particular string object.

If you had multiple arguments to your print function the utility becomes a little clearer:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
y = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
z = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])

print("x:\n", x, y, z)
```

Out:

```
x:
 [[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]] [[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]] [[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]]
```

And:

```
print("x:\n{}\n\n{}\n\n{}".format(x, y, z))
```

Out:

```
x:
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]]

[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]]

[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]]
```

Or even:

```
a_list_of_terms = ['the', 'knights', 'who', 'say', 'ni']


print("{}".format(a_list_of_terms))
```

Out:

```
['the', 'knights', 'who', 'say', 'ni']
```

Or you can unpack a list using `*` for:

```
print("We are {} {} {} and we demand a shrubbery.".format(*a_list_of_terms))
```

Out:

```
'We are the knights who and we demand a shrubbery.'
```

You can find the official documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)